# How can I create a Powershell Cmdlet parameter in C# that behaves as a switch?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am using the **System.Management.Automation** namespace in C# in order to expose my class library in a Powershell module. In some of the cmdlets, I would like to provide an optional parameter that behaves like a switch (i.e. if it's included, that parameter is set to true).  I've seen parameters in other Powershell Cmdlets behave this way, but I haven't seen a way to accomplish this using the C# interface.  The closest I can come is a parameter that accepts boolean:

```
[Parameter(HelpMessage = "If enabled, no confirmation prompt will appear")]
public bool Quiet { get; set; } = false;
```

However in execution, the parameter is not acceptable on it's own, it needs to be accompanied by a value:

```
New-Widget -Path C:\temp\myfile.abc -Quiet $True
```

If possible, I'd like *Quiet* to be able to be set to true just by virtue of the parameter being there:

```
New-Widget -Path C:\temp\myfile.abc -Quiet
```

Is this possible?

Comment: see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485249/detecting-a-powershell-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485249/detecting-a-powershell-switch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you're looking for is [`SwitchParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.switchparameter), not `bool`:

> Type used to define a parameter on a cmdlet script of function that **can only be used as a switch.**

So the parameter signature you want is:

```
[Parameter(HelpMessage = "If enabled, no confirmation prompt will appear")]
public SwitchParameter Quiet { get; set; } = false;
```

Implicit conversions (both ways) exist for `bool`, so it should be a simple drop-in replacement in your existing cmdlet class.

---

Beware that since `SwitchParameter` is the only parameter type for which PowerShell does not expect any argument(s), `Command-Name -Quiet $true` won't actually do what you think - the `$true` token will instead be interpreted as a positional or unbound argument, unrelated to `-Quiet`.

The only way to pass an explicit value to a `SwithParameter` is with a tight binding, like so:

```
Command-Name -Quiet:$true
```

For this reason, the *default value* of a `SwitchParameter` should *never* be set to `true`/`$true`, since it'll force the user to use the awkward tight value binding syntax as shown above.

Comment: Thank you very much!